# Configuring the Enterprise Library DAAB for use in a SharePoint timer job

Tags: sharepoint-2010, enterprise-library, timer-jobs, daab

I am trying to set up a timer job which uses the Enterprise Library DAAB. The DAAB is working fine in the conext of the the front end servers (aspx page), where the data connection is retrieved from the web.config. But in the context of a timer job, the call fails somewhere near DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("connection_name"), complaining my connection is not defined in the configuration.

My question is, where is it looking for this configuration file / how should I set this up?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: I resolved this myself. Along side the OWSTIMER.EXE is an OWSTIMER.EXE.CONFIG file. I just used the enterprise library configuration tool to set up my database connections there, and restarted the timer service. Works fine now.

Comment: Post your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copying down my comment so I can mark this answered.

Along side the OWSTIMER.EXE is an OWSTIMER.EXE.CONFIG file. I just used the enterprise library configuration tool to set up my database connections there, and restarted the timer service. Works fine now. –